# Questions with 10k+ score overflow in close dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed

```
<div title="Combined score of the question and all answers" class="answer-votes extra-large">11571</div>
```

As others recent bug reports, this one is minor bug, too and happens once a year. (11571 votes)

Comment: Whoa. ***11,571 duplicate suggestions for hidden features of C#?***

Comment: @Chris: I think only 94. 11571 total votes on question + answers?

Comment: Whoops! Right you are. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I actually think this is 10k+, not 1k+...

Comment: @Chris: correct, edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number shown is, as noted by the caption, the total score of the question and all answers, intended to show the net wisdom (or something *like* wisdom) in that question.

It should, however, have been using the "11.6k" abbreviated form. This has<sup>#</sup> been corrected (the caption now<sup>#</sup> also includes the unabbreviated score, just in case you care about the last few votes).

<sub>#=next build</sub>